# iOS: a way to define a general object inside an NSArray in Swift

Tags: ios, oop, swift

In Swift I have this object City:

```
class City {

    var name:String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    var file:String?
    var description:String?
}
```

now in my viewcontroller I fill an array with these type of objects and I want to fill a tableview, but I'm not able to access at the property of this object.

I show you the code, that doesn't take the property "file":

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = menu_list.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("list_cell") as ListCell
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    var obj = list_element.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    var name = obj.file
    return cell
}
```

Now STOP! You can suggest me to add this "as City"

```
var obj = list_element.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as City
```

but I don't know what type of objects is filled my array, I have other object as Country and State, then what's the way to have a general managing of objects? In obj-c I did it with "id" but in swift?

Comment: What about using `as?` `var element = list_element.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) if let obj = element  as? City { name = obj.file } else if let obj = element as? State { // Do something else}`

Comment: mmmm with obj-c is more simple... you can use "id"

Comment: Even in obj-c you need to cast the pointer like `City *c = (City *)idObject`. Am I wrong? Here we have AnyObject. `var element: AnyObject = list_element.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)` when casting you can protect against a crash by using `if let with as?`.

Comment: no the cast in obj-c it's not necessary... you can access to object property without problems, now if I try to access in this way to element 'var element: AnyObject = list_element.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)' it's not possible...but thanks  I proceed with if-else block

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can use an `NSArray` if you like, you just have to make sure all of your objects are subclasses of `NSObject`.  Swift also allows you to declare an array of type `[Any]` which can hold any type.  You then use conditional cast `as?` to work with the objects:

```
class City {

}

class Country {

}

class State {

}

var places = [Any]()

places.append(City())
places.append(State())
places.append(Country())
places.append(Country())
places.append(13)

for place in places {
    if let loc = place as? City {
        println("processing city")
    }
    if let loc = place as? State {
        println("processing state")
    }
    if let loc = place as? Country {
        println("processing country")
    }
}
```

You can also use a `switch` to determine the type:

```
for place in places {
    switch place {
    case let loc as City:
        println("I see a city")
    case let loc as State:
        println("I see a state")
    case let loc as Country:
        println("I see a country")
    default:
        println("I don't know what it is")
    }
}
```

If all you are putting in your array of `places` is `City`, `State`, and `Country` objects, it would be better form to have those three classes derive from a base class (let's call it `Location`) and then have your array of places be of type `[Location]`.